# Is it possible to specify a context-sensitive, "depth-agnostic" rewrite rule?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I'm using the term "depth-agnostic" in this post to describe structural patterns featuring a "target" sub-pattern that can occur "at any depth" relative to one or more "context" sub-patterns.

As a simple example of a "depth-agnostic" pattern, consider the following rewrite rule:

> RR1
>
> replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` contained *somewhere* within some expression `_CTX`.<sup>1</sup>

Here the target and context sub-patterns are `X_TGT` and `_CTX`, respectively.  The depth-agnostic bit comes in as the phrase "*somewhere* within".

In other words, RR1 says to find expressions that look like

```
… CTX[ … y0[ … y1[ … … yk[ … TGT[ … ] … ] … … ] … ] … ] …
```

...(where the number of nested subexpressions `y0`, `y1`, ..., `yk` is indeterminate), and rewrite them as

```
… CTX[ … y0[ … y1[ … … yk[ … WRAP[TGT[ … ]] … ] … … ] … ] … ] …
```

Thus, if we defined

```
ping = foo[{1, CTX[bar[2,  3, {TGT[0], 4} ]]}];
ding = foo[{1, CTX[bar[2, {3, {TGT[0], 4}}]]}];
pong = foo[{1, baz[bar[2,  3, {TGT[0], 4} ]]}];
```

then, according to RR1, `ping` would be changed to

```
foo[{1, CTX[bar[2,  3, {WRAP[TGT[0]], 4} ]]}]
```

...and `ding` would be changed to

```
foo[{1, CTX[bar[2, {3, {WRAP[TGT[0]], 4}}]]}]
```

On the other hand, `pong` would be unaffected by RR1, even though it contains an expression `_TGT`, because this expression does not occur "*somewhere* within an expression `_CTX`".

The problem is

> how to implement a rewrite rule that features such a "depth-agnostic" pattern in *Mathematica*?

To see why "depth-agnosticity" is an issue, consider rewrite rule RR2 below, identical in every way to RR1, except that it specifies a single, unambiguous depth for the target relative to the context sub-pattern (IOW, it is not "depth-agnostic"):

> RR2
>
> replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` contained *at a depth of 3 within* some expression `_CTX`.

As shown below, implementing RR2 in *Mathematica* is straightforward (though, admittedly, a bit tedious), but unfortunately, it is nowhere as general as RR1 (e.g. RR2 affects only `ping`, not `ding`).

Here's one (rather uninspired) implementation of RR2 in action:

```
{ping, ding, pong} /.
  CTX[a1___, h1_[a2___, h2_[a3___, X_TGT, z3___], z2___], z1___] -> 
  CTX[a1, h1[a2, h2[a3, WRAP[X], z3], z2], z1] // TableForm

foo[{1, CTX[bar[2, 3, {WRAP[TGT[0]], 4}]]}]
foo[{1, CTX[bar[2, {3, {TGT[0], 4}}]]}]
foo[{1, baz[bar[2, 3, {TGT[0], 4}]]}]
```

This implementation fulfills the earlier assertions about RR2: it like RR1 with respect to `ping` (affects it) and `pong` (does not affect it), but not with respect to `ding` (RR1 affects `ding` but RR2 doesn't).

---

There are at least two important generalizations of the ideas described above.  The first one is the situation in which there are multiple context sub-patterns that are themselves at indeterminate depths relative to each other.  For example:

> RR3
>
> replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` and being contained *somewhere* within some expression `_CTX` that is itself contained *somewhere* within some expression `_List`.

The second generalization could be expressed as allowing "negative depths", or in other words, patterns in which the context sub-pattern is contained within the target subpattern.  For example:

> RR4
>
> replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` containing *somewhere* within it some expression `_CTX`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>In this post I will resort to Mathematica's notation for patterns.  Namely, `_H` denotes a pattern matching any expression having head `H`, and `X_H` denotes a pattern matching any expression (henceforth referred to as `X`) having head `H`.  I will abuse this notation slightly, writing "an expression `_H`" as shorthand for "an expression matching the pattern `_H`", and "an expression `X_H`" as shorthand for "an expression (henceforth referred to as `X`) matching the pattern `_H`.)</sup>

Comment: I think you want something similar to what was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451802/pattern-to-match-only-children-of-certain-elements/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ReplaceAll` or `/.`, which is what you used, replaces at all levels (or depths). If you need to target a particular level/depth, then use `Replace`. To target expressions that contain/don't contain a particular term, use `FreeQ` Here's how you can write your replacement rules for each of the cases (replace `expr` with whatever you have):

> **RR1:** replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` contained somewhere within some expression `_CTX`

```
expr /. x_CTX :>  (x /. TGT :> Composition[WRAP, TGT])
```

or

```
expr /. x_CTX :> (x /. y_TGT :> WRAP[y])
```

---

> **RR2:** replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` contained at a depth of 3 within some expression `_CTX`.

```
expr /. x_CTX :> Replace[x, y_TGT :> WRAP[y], {3}]
```

and similarly using `Composition`.

---

> **RR3:** replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` and being contained somewhere within some expression `_CTX` that is itself contained somewhere within some expression `_List`.

```
expr /. l_List :> (l /. x_CTX :> (x /. y_TGT :> WRAP[y]))
```

---

> **RR4:** replace with the expression `WRAP[X]` any expression `X_TGT` containing somewhere within it some expression `_CTX`.

```
expr /. y_TGT :> WRAP[y] /; ! FreeQ[y, CTX]
```

Comment: ++Thanks!  This goes a long way.  Minor follow-up comment/question: for **RR1**-**RR3**, it looks to me like, for the innermost replacement, `Rule` may be used instead of `RuleDelayed`...  I haven't yet come up with a case that would distinguish a clear preference for one (of `Rule` vs `RuleDelayed`) over the other.

Comment: @kjo I would not use `Rule` except in rather special circumstances, since `Rule` does not properly scope pattern variables.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks!