# Replace pattern within a specific pattern only

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have expressions like

```
tc*Cos[2*w*(t0+tc)]
```

and I want to replace `tc` by something else, but only if it occurs inside `Cos`, i.e. the outer `tc` should remain as is. Is there any way of specifying the context in which `Replace` should act? Maybe some clever pattern tricks?

Note that the actual expressions I'm working on are more complicated and consist of more (similar) terms, so just skipping over the first occurrence isn't going to cut it.

Thanks!

Comment: `ReplaceAll[c_Cos?(Not@*FreeQ[tc]):>ReplaceAll[c, tc->new]]` should do it. It's not a nice pattern to work with. Will be slow. But if the `tc` can appear in an arbitrary expression within `Cos` then there's not too much else I know to do.

Comment: The solution by QuantumDot below works like a charm! Also, in the mean time I've found a related, more general question (with answers) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11331/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-context-sensitive-depth-agnostic-rewrite-rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is: if you have

```
expr = tc*Cos[2*w*(t0+tc)]
```

Then to make the replacement, use

```
expr /. (Cos[arg_] :> Cos[arg /. tc -> new])
```

> `tc Cos[2 (new + t0) w]`